# Does passing a control as parameter causes an enough performance hit?

Tags: c#, asp.net, optimization, coding-style

What is better/preferred - Creating a method of 2 lines which accepts a web control as a parameter, operates on it and is called from 3-4 places within the same code file or writing those 2 lines at the 3-4 places and not creating the method?

P.S. The control I am referring here is a textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All it is passing is a reference. There will be no significant cost to this *whatsoever*. If the method is small and linear, the JIT may even choose to inline it - but ultimately, this is **not** going to make any difference.

Stick with the method approach - then you only have one place to maintain.

Comment: +2.. 1 for the answer and 1 for the light-speed beating reply timings.. :)

Answer (score 0):

For maintainability it is better to break out the lines to a method.

Performance wise you will not notice any difference at all.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're working on code that needs to run in a Nuclear Powerplant or a NASA landrover on Mars, you're always better of writing code that is easier for YOU to maintain! And that means refactoring your code so you never repeat yourself.

Theoretically its of course faster to have the instructions inline and not call a method, but in practice it far outweighs the cons maintaining it.

Comment: Why wouldn't that be equally important in a Nuclear Powerplant on in a Mars rover? I have heard that the Mars rovers run debug code printing debug stuff to the console up there because that was the code they have run most and tested with, hence the code they shipped.

Comment: I would assume that in those environments you would need to squeeze as much performance out of every bits and bytes you had and if saving a few cycles of not having to call a method, maintaining callstack etc. it could be an acceptable trade off. But maybe im wrong, and this only applied when we were running on 2mhz machines with 64kbit of ram.

Comment: those are the places you really really really don't want it to go wrong, therefore the need for excellent readability and maintainability is of uttermost importance.

Answer (score 0):

Careful where the method that modifies the control resides. If the method is part of another class, then passing controls to it will break the encapsulation of the class that owns the control.

Answer (score 0):

The DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle says that you create the method and call it the 3-4 times. The performance hit is so minimal that it really isn't worth thinking about unless the consequence of those billionths of a second outweigh the additional overhead of maintaining the code 3-4 times over.

In short, unless you can really really really justify the additional maintenance over grabbing every last processor cycle* overhead then create the method.

(*) Given this is a textbox and therefore most likely a business application your biggest performance worries more likely are databases and webservices.